# Can the SAME histone tail have both H3K4me3 and H3K27me3?

Tags: epigenetics

I'm studying bivalent promoters and enhancers. I understand that the same region of genome can have both H3K4me3 and H3K27me3.
But can they occur on the same histone tail?
Please provide me with a reference to support your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-04836-y) suggests that people have tested if two proteins can bind on a histone tail that contains both epigenetic marks. This implies that indeed both markings can be on the same tail.

"Next, we investigated if a histone tail bearing both H3K4me3 and H3K27me3 marks can be combinatorially recognized by SHL."